# Every time I route to a new page I have to check the server with axios in a Vue JS app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

So every time, I route to a new page on the click of certain divs I have to check if the name of the div exists in the server with axios and display all the information about the div clicked from the server. I was hoping to use the `router.beforeEach` methods or an `@click` method then `router.addRoute` and then `router.push`. Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: How are you handling clicks on the divs? Why not do the check inside the click handler?

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far (code-wise)? Also, an alternative solution would be a middleware (doing that for every path) for you.

Comment: I am creating it right now. I am trying to create a dynamic router that goes through data and then checks if data exists or not. In my situation I think checking inside the click handler would be ideal